Woman experiences weird things in her mother's old house
I have seen a movie a while back, but can't remember the name or too many details. 
There was a woman living in a house that used to belong to her mother. I'm pretty sure she was a cop, but I'm not sure. She lived in her mother's house and her sister was missing. Sometimes at night she would do something in her kitchen and when she went to look, the fridge was open and a pot of pickles would be on the floor. She and her sister were always really scared of the closet. In the end it turns out a man is living under the house and eating the pickles at night, I believe he was the mother's brother and he killed her sister and a police man...
I know this probably doesn't make a lot of sense, but maybe someone knows what movie it is.

You're looking for The Pact from 2012.

Nichole Barlow comes to San Pedro with her daughter Eva to attend the funeral of her mother. She calls her estranged sister Annie to help her to resolve pending businesses, but Annie is too traumatized with the bad treatment spent by their mother and does not want to return to their childhood home. Nichole convinces her sister to come and she arrives to the funeral. However, Nichole goes missing and Eva stays with Nichole's cousin Liz. When Liz also disappears, Annie claims that supernatural events happen in the house but she becomes the prime-suspect.

The pickle jar, the ending with her uncle in a secret room under the house, it's all there. The trailer:



